# Why does the weak reference not get collected in this simple F# example?

Tags: f#, garbage-collection, weak-references

```ml
open System

let WeakReferenceExample() =
    let mutable obj = new Object();
    let weak = new WeakReference(obj);

    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("IsAlive: {0}\nobj <> null is {1}\n---", weak.IsAlive, obj <> null);

    obj <- null;
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("IsAlive: {0}", weak.IsAlive);

WeakReferenceExample()
Console.ReadKey()
```

Translated from the [Rx In Action](https://github.com/tamirdresher/RxInAction/blob/0e530d133848f247ff727ac7f55bd1e6eef18191/CH11/ResourceHandling/Program.cs#L98) book sample. The above when run gives the following output which is different than what I get when I compile it in C# and run it.

```
IsAlive: True
obj <> null is True
---
IsAlive: True
```

Why is the weak reference not getting collected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the measurement affects the result.

The underlying cause is compiler (reverse?) optimizations for better locals during Debugging.

When you write:

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3]
let list2 = [3; 4; 5]
printfn "%b" (list1 = list2)
```

This elaborates every sub-expression to:

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3]
let list2 = [3; 4; 5] 
let list1' = list1
let list2' = list2
let is_eq = list1'.Equals(list2')
printfn "%b" (is_eq)
```

Now you can begin to guess where this is going.

```
 Console.WriteLine("IsAlive: {0}\nobj <> null is {1}\n---", weak.IsAlive, obj <> null);
```

Elaborates to:

```
    let isAlive = weak.IsAlive
    let obj' = obj
    let isNotNull = obj' <> null
    Console.WriteLine("IsAlive: {0}\nobj <> null is {1}\n---", isAlive, isNotNull);
```

Now when you do:

```
    obj <- null;
    GC.Collect();
```

note that a reference still exists in `obj'`.

So the object won't be collected during the GC pass.
And that's what `WeakReference` is showing.

So interestingly enough, if you comment out the first `Console.Writeline`, there's no sub-expression elaboration, hence no references, and you get:

```
IsAlive: False
```

Or you could just build it in **Release** mode.