# Why does reference equality for functions which are bound to the same variable return false?

Tags: f#

```ml
let f x = System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x,x)

f id // false
```

I thought that at first it might because a function could be converted to a closure multiple times, but the above disproves that. Why does that last line return `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have optimizations turned on. This time it's [the opposite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989884/why-does-the-weak-reference-not-get-collected-in-this-simple-f-example).

What happens if inlining is turned on?

`id` will be rewritten to an instance of `idFuncClass <: FSharpFunc`.

The whole expression will be rewritten to:

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(new fsharpfun1(), new fsharpfun1())
```

You can turning off inlining with:

```
[<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)>]
let f x = System.Object.ReferenceEquals(x,x)
```

You'll find that the comparison works again.
But the bigger take-away is this - comparing two functions in F# is undefined behavior. In fact a function type doesn't even implement equality.

```
let illegal = id = id //this won't compile
```

Here's the relevant section in the F# Spec:

> #### 6.9.24 Values with Underspecified Object Identity and Type Identity
>
> The CLI and F# support operations that detect object identity — that is, whether two object references refer to the same “physical” object.
>
> For example, `System.Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)` returns true if the two object references refer to the same object. Similarly, `GetHashCode()` returns a hash code that is partly based on physical object identity ...
>
> The results of these operations are underspecified when used with values of the following F# types:
>
> - Function types
> - Tuple types
> - Immutable record types
> - Union types
> - Boxed immutable value types
>
> For two values of such types, the results of `System.Object.ReferenceEquals` and
> `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode` are underspecified; however, the operations terminate and do not raise exceptions.
>
> An implementation of F# is not required to define the results of these
> operations for values of these types.

What the spec advises is to treat the actual function-type and its CLR implementations as a black-box.